# Docker up command exited with code 0 on another machine

Tags: django, sqlite, docker

Docker container for my app works fine on my system, while it doesn't on others'.

I tried the following commands to re-run my docker container on a different machine:

```
$docker-compose build
$docker-up
```

(this is where it fails !)

**Docker**

```
FROM python:3.6.8
MAINTAINER angy@localhost     
COPY ./ /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp      
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt       
#CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  python:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/myapp
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

> Starting angy_proj_python_1_b395bdd740ea ... done
>   Attaching to angy_proj_python_1_b395bdd740ea
>   angy_proj_python_1_b395bdd740ea exited with code 0

Comment: You should verify that current directory on the other machine is in a location that Docker is allowed to make volumes from. Otherwise it could be failing when it is unable to mount the current directory as a volume.

Comment: Better still, delete the `volumes:` and run the code that’s built into the image.  That makes the image independent of the system you’re running it on and whatever happens to be on that local system.  (If you need a copy of the code everywhere anyways, it’s simpler to just use the host Python.)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have the CMD line commented out

```
#CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

so the container will not a daemon to run and would exit immediately because its not doing anything. remove the # and see if that solves the problem

Comment: You are right. Although, I just added command: sleep infinity at the end of the yml file. It's a dirty fix, I know

Comment: If that's the case I assume that your server script is forking to a background process ID, while your fix works, you'd probably like the container to reset if the server crashes, which will not happen if the infinite sleep is what's keeping it alive.

Comment: Yes, I added an appropriate command to run the server. Works well!